# How to GRANT CREATE INTEGRATION to role SYSADMIN

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We want to give SYSADMIN the privilege to create integrations for an automated pipeline.

We ran the following with the ACCOUNTADMIN role but got a syntax error

```sql
GRANT CREATE INTEGRATION TO ROLE SYSADMIN;
```

What is the correct statement for this?

Comment: you should mark one of the answers as an answer; maybe delete your self answer and mark the answer with additional info.

Answer (score 2):

GRANT CREATE INTEGRATION ON ACCOUNT TO ROLE SYSADMIN;

You can also refer to the syntax shared in the link below for the format of granting the privileges to roles
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/grant-privilege.html#syntax

Answer (score 0):

Answer -

```sql
GRANT CREATE INTEGRATION ON ACCOUNT TO ROLE SYSADMIN;
```